# why my HOC Component is working properly ? #React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hoc

2 components :- ClickCounter, mouseHoverCounter !
1 HOC component to do the counting work.

earlier I was counting the click and mouse hover by writing separate counter method in each component(cliccounter,mousehovecounter),
but
now, I'm trying to pass the component into hoc counter & get the new component with only one change , where I'm passing a props to originalComponent and returning it to see the behavior but its now working...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import updatedComponent from './hocCounter'

class ClickCounter extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             counter:0
        }
    }

    ClickCounterHandler = () =>{
        this.setState((prevState)=>{
            return {counter:prevState.counter+1}
        })
    }

    render() {
        const count=this.state.counter
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.ClickCounterHandler}>{this.props.name} Clicked {count} Times</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default updatedComponent(ClickCounter)
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import updatedComponent from './hocCounter'

class HoverMouseCounter extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             counter:0
        }
    }
    MouseOverCounter(){
        this.setState((prevState)=>{
            return {counter:prevState.counter+1}
        })
    }

    render() {
        const count=this.state.counter
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 onMouseOver={this.MouseOverCounter.bind(this)}>{this.props.name} Hovered For {count} Time(s)</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default updatedComponent(HoverMouseCounter)
```

```
import React from 'react'

const updatedComponent = originalComponent => {

    class newComponent extends React.Component {
        render(){
            return <originalComponent name='Harsh'/>
        }
    }
    return newComponent
}

export default updatedComponent
```

In App.js, I'm returning

```
<ClickCounter></ClickCounter>
<HoverMouseCounter></HoverMouseCounter>
```

this only !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the error in the console,
`index.js:1 Warning: <originalComponent /> is using incorrect casing. Use PascalCase for React components, or lowercase for HTML elements. at originalComponent`

This means You are using the small letter in `originalComponent`
React components are expected to start with a capital letter

Try this in you HOC component

```
import React from 'react'

const updatedComponent = OriginalComponent => {

    class NewComponent extends React.Component {
        render(){
            return <OriginalComponent name='Harsh'/>
        }
    }
    return NewComponent
}

export default updatedComponent
```